# else condition is working even if is true

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using codigniter 3.1.2 and using simple if condition in php but really confused when I checked my condition is true getting result from else condition as well and if as well mean getting data in from both cases.

```
 public function editexperience($UserID = 0, $ID = 0) {
    if ($this->Access->HaveAccess('Edit')) {
        $Row = $this->Experience->Row($ID);
        if ($ID > 0 && $Row){
            print_r($Row);

            Def(array(
                'Update'=>'users/submit/updateexperience/'
            ),'Actions');
            $User = $this->Model->Row(intval($UserID), '', 'CTRY.Currency');
            $ID = intval($ID);
            $Data['Row'] = $Row;
            Def($Row,'Row');
            $Data['Title'] = 'Edit Experience';
            $Data['Fields'] = $this->GetExperienceFields($User->Currency, true);
            $this->Main->SetPage('Helper/Edit', $Data, true);
        } else {
            TempNote('There is problem while getting request data!', 'Error');
            redirect(URI(_E('{Page.List}'), true), 'refresh');
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

In code I mentioned if I have Row then load template of edit.

Suppose:

I have Row and its loading edit template and also showing the error of else condition really confuse what is happening.

My PHP version is 5.6.31

TempNote Function

```
function TempNote($Message, $Type) {
    //Prepare Data
    $Current = array('Message'=>$Message,'Type'=>$Type);
    //Get current instance
    $Ins = & get_instance();
    $Old = $Ins->Main->Messages;

    // If another is already set and that should not be current
    if (!empty($Old)) {
        foreach ($Old as $Key=>$Now) {
            if ($Now === $Current){
                unset($Old[$Key]);
            }
        }
    }
    $Ins->Main->Messages[] = $Current;
    $Ins->session->set_flashdata('Message', $Ins->Main->Messages);
}
```

Comment: What is `def()`

Comment: what else condition? Else is if the if condition == false - so your conditional is going wrong. Var dump $ID and $Row individually, probably holding values you're not expecting

Comment: Is this a class methods code?

Comment: def is custom function which is define array constant. 
yes its class method code

Comment: Do as @treyBake suggests, show us a `var_dump()` of `$ID` and `$Row`

Comment: @treyBake i'm simply saying if i have $Row then load edit template and its loading but its also showing error of else condition

Comment: i did var_dump and getting data in $ID and $Row perfectly

Comment: and i more thing else error shows sometime and sometime its hide not shows

Comment: Is this in a loop? Is it possible you're getting the row on the first iteration and the error on a later one?

Comment: I would cast $ID to int And check that it Is Positive yet before attempting to load the row. And make sure you are not calling this code multiple times with differrent arguments... PHP Is definitely NOT executing both branches at the same time...

Comment: OH And tempNote call Is followed by redirect? Is it storing the note into session? Make sure the session Is cleared when the message Is displayed.

Comment: TempNote store data in session and then page redirect

Comment: @slepic check tempnote function

Comment: I dont know codeigniter. But from the logic i would say that the page you are redirecting to Is not displaying the message And therefore some other page Is but the message Is already irrelevant on whatever page comes next.

Comment: Ah you included the function in your op, i thought IT was codeigniter function... But anyway you have to make sure the messages Are removed from session Once displayed And also make sure this happens on the page you redirect to.

Comment: i am doing check comment into my function i'm checking if previously have any message unset it

Comment: Reformatted code to make more readable.